# using ENUM in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, c++-cli, visual-studio-2013

I have tried to write some simple code in C++, but when I debug it, the declared variable of some enum type does not get an assigned value. The code I refer to is as follows:

```
namespace GEORGE { 
    //...
    public enum FUNCTIONITEM { VARIABLE, FUNCTION, NUMBER };
    //...
}
```

then, in another file, i have the following:

```
//... 
using namespace GEORGE;

private System::Void AFunction(...)
{
    //...
    FUNCTIONITEM anItem;
    //...
    if (condition)
       anItem = VARIABLE;
    else
       amitem = NUMBER;
    //...
}
```

When I debug the above, when the condition is true, it goes and processes the first `anItem = VARIABLE;`

But it does not assign any value to it (the Watch of anItem in the debugger says: `<undefined value>`, after the line has been processed. When I declare anItem as int, it assigns the value 0, as I expected. I'd think though that declaring anItem as FUNCTIONITEM should be fine, so I am quite surprised. Any ideas?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: And what do you expect it to do? When the condition is true, `anItem` should equal `VARIABLE`

Comment: If you copied and pasted this code here, then you misspelled the variable in the else.

Comment: With `System::`, this looks like C++/CLI, and should be tagged as such as it can be very different.

Comment: Please show a complete program. An SSCCE. Perhaps the compiler removes the variable since you never refer to it elsewhere. But we don't know what you real program looks like. SSCCE please.

Comment: Use the *enum class* keyword in managed code.

Comment: David the complete program (so far) is more than 1000 lines long and probably quite messy too (as I am still experimenting with things). Josh, I did indeed misspell the variable in the else statement, it should have been anItem.

Comment: @user David did not request *"the program"*. He asked for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), a **minimal** testcase that exposes the issue you are having. Getting help involves effort at your end.

Comment: Hans Passant, this worked (the enum class), with the slight side-effect that it initialised all instances to a default value of VARIABLE. So I have now a solution (and I could change the enum to have an NOTYETDEFINED for the default value before the VARIABLE), but is that as efficient memorywise as a simple enum? thanks for your help anyway, was really struggling with this!

Comment: It's clear that you don't understand much of this. Adding a new value to indicate (not defined) is not the solution. Not that it's remotely clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed I dont. I've been working to produce an SSCCE but its tricky. I'll post the SSCCE once I've managed to build it. I am using Forms, by the way, if that helps at all.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
if (condition)
   anItem = VARIABLE;
else
   amitem = NUMBER;
```

use

```
if (condition)
   anItem = FUNCTIONITEM::VARIABLE;
else
   amitem = FUNCTIONITEM::NUMBER;
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that too (to add FUNCTIONITEM:: before VARIABLE or NUMBER) without further success :( .

Comment: It's an unscoped enumeration, so this will just prevent it compiling.